# Error takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Hi i am trying to plot points in a google map by indexing the dictionary with a foor loop, have this dictionary of lat:long

```
 latlon = {32.1243973: -101.8856125, 32.666694: -104.233502, 32.222012:
 -101.819122, 32.53151: -103.353018, 32.668496: -104.235722, 32.1041336: -101.8818588}
```

And i have this code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        map = Map()
        for latitude, longitude in latlon.iteritems():
            map.add_point(latitude, longitude)
```

I get the error **TypeError: add_point() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)**

I am giving only latitude and longitude why it says i am giving 3 arguments?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: addint the class map:

```
class Map(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._points = []
    def add_point(self, coordinates):
        self._points.append(coordinates)
    def __str__(self):
        centerLat = sum(( x[0] for x in self._points )) / len(self._points)
        centerLon = sum(( x[1] for x in self._points )) / len(self._points)
        markersCode = "\n".join(
            [ """new google.maps.Marker({{
                position: new google.maps.LatLng({lat}, {lon}),
                map: map
                }});""".format(lat=x[0], lon=x[1]) for x in self._points
            ])
        return """
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
            <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 100%; width: 100%"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var map;
                function show_map() {{
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {{
                        zoom: 8,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng({centerLat}, {centerLon})
                    }});
                    {markersCode}
                }}
                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', show_map);
            </script>
        """.format(centerLat=centerLat, centerLon=centerLon,
                   markersCode=markersCode)
```

Comment: calling a class method automatically sends itself as an argument. What class is `map`?

Comment: We have no idea what type of object `map` is, hence no idea which function/method `map.add_point()` is. Your code is not reproducible. Please add more code to the snippet.

Comment: What happens if you try `for ll in latlon.iteritems(): map.add_point(ll)`?

Answer (score 1):

`add_point` seems to want the latitude & longitude as a single object; something like this:

```
for ll in latlon.iteritems(): 
    map.add_point(ll)
```

Answer (score 0):

addPoint() is supposed to take both coordinates as one parameter.

Another way to write `map.addPoint(p)` is `Map.addPoint(map, p)`.  From the second example, you can see why you were getting an error by having too many parameters.

You can call your function like this to include both latitude and longitude in one parameter:

```
for i in latlon.iteritems:
    map.addPoint(i)
```